# Azure Deployment Source, choose Startup Project to Build

Tags: azure, build-process, azure-deployment

The company I currently work for has a solution with 3 projects.

_Common... which was originally a Web project, but then changed to a Class Library.

Website1... Which is a website

Website2... Completely different website.

In Azure, we have a Deployment configuration so whenever our BitBucket Repo gets a checkin, it should build and deploy the solution.

Unfortunately, it seems like _Common is getting built as the target project.  Which is breaking Azure.

**ALSO Unfortunately**, we have Two DIFFERENT Products (Website1 and Website2) which are in Two Different Azure Apps.  They are both looking at the same BitBucket Repo, and both building whenever a checkin happens... but both are building _Common.

Can I have our "Website1" Azure App build the solution with Website1 as the startup project, and have our "Website2" Azure App build the solution with "Website2" As the startup project?

This obviously won't work to set the default project in Github, since we still need two different builds with two different startup projects.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have multiple websites in the solution, and when deploying to Azure (Web App) you want to specify which website to deploy?  If so, add an App Setting called `Project` with a relative path to the `*.csproj` of the website that you want deployed (e.g. `Website1\Website1.csproj`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certanly can!

Go to your "Website1" Web App and go to **Settings** > **Application Settings**.

#### If you are using .Net Framework 4.5 or lower

Add a setting called **Project**, which value points to the **CSPROJ file** you want to build, using the full path from the repository root folder.

#### If you are using ASP.NET Core 1.0 / ASP.NET 5

Add a setting called **Project**, which value points to the **folder** that contains the *project.json* file of the project you want to deploy, *do not include the filename in the path*.

Comment: Thank you for posting this as an answer, and thank you for the more detail than Brendan.  Though Brendan's was probably fine.  I am using this method right now and am currently hitting a wall that is probably related to the way this solution and its projects are set up.  If I have a followup question, I'll ask here.  If I get it sorted and this works, I'll take action on this answer.  I may end up adding a slight bit of detail myself, but this gets me on the right track so far.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using .Net Framework 4.5 (or lower) or Core? I found out that there are some tweaks when you are referencing external DLLs instead of projects in the same repo. Let me know if you need any other help regarding the scenario.

Comment: No, my remaining issue was regarding App_Code and App_GlobalResources were being pulled in by Azure and breaking the site.  So I had to fix the settings that were left messy by the previous generation.  All fix'd!